# Location is working but its not tracking my distrance travelled in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, cllocationmanager

I'm making an app for one of my courses. It is supposed to track the distance traveled and update a label to show how far they've gone. When I open the app it asks for permission to track location. The mapView works, it follows the location but the label is never updated to show the distance traveled. I've added my code below, any help is greatly appreciated!

```
    //
    //  ViewController.swift
    //  location_tracker
    //
    //  Created by Dale McCaughan on 2016-10-19.
    //  Copyright © 2016 Dale McCaughan. All rights reserved.
    //

    import UIKit
    import CoreLocation
    import MapKit

    class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate, MKMapViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var theMap: MKMapView!
    @IBOutlet weak var l: UILabel!

    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    var startLocation: CLLocation!
    var monitoredRegions: Dictionary<String, NSDate> = [:]

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden =  true
        self.navigationController?.isToolbarHidden = false;

    //Status bar style and visibility
    UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .lightContent

    //Change status bar color
    let statusBar: UIView = UIApplication.shared.value(forKey: "statusBar") as! UIView
    //if statusBar.respondsToSelector("setBackgroundColor:") {
    statusBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    //}

    UIToolbar.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor.white

}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //Setup the Location Manager
    locationManager.delegate = self;
    locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters;
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;

    //Setup the Map View
    theMap.delegate = self
    theMap.showsUserLocation = true
    theMap.userTrackingMode = .follow

    // setup test data

}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    // status is not determined
    if CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .notDetermined {
        locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    }
        // authorization were denied
    else if CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .denied {
        showAlert("Location services were previously denied. Please enable location services for this app in Settings.")
    }
        // we do have authorization
    else if CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .authorizedAlways {
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }
}

// MARK: - MKMapViewDelegate

func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, rendererFor overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer {
    let circleRenderer = MKCircleRenderer(overlay: overlay)
    circleRenderer.strokeColor = UIColor.red
    circleRenderer.lineWidth = 1.0
    return circleRenderer
}

@IBAction func resetDistance(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    startLocation = nil
}

// MARK: - CLLocationManagerDelegate

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didEnterRegion region: CLRegion) {
    showAlert("enter \(region.identifier)")
    monitoredRegions[region.identifier] = Date() as NSDate?
    l.text = "in location manager1"
}

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didExitRegion region: CLRegion) {
    showAlert("exit \(region.identifier)")
    monitoredRegions.removeValue(forKey: region.identifier)
    l.text = "in location manager2"
}

var lastLocation: CLLocation!
var traveledDistance:Double = 0

func locationManager(manager:CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations:[AnyObject]) {

    if let firstLocation = locations.first as? CLLocation
    {
        theMap.setCenter(firstLocation.coordinate, animated: true)

        let region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(firstLocation.coordinate, 1000, 1000)
        theMap.setRegion(region, animated: true)

        if let oldLocation = lastLocation {
            let delta: CLLocationDistance = firstLocation.distance(from: lastLocation)
            traveledDistance += delta
        }

        lastLocation = firstLocation
    }
    l.text = String(format: "%.3f", traveledDistance/1000) + " kilometers"

}

// MARK: - Helpers

func showAlert(_ title: String) {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .default, handler: { (action) in
        alert.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }))
    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
}
```

Comment: Have you done any debugging to see where the code breaks exactly? In its current form, this is too broad for a SO question, you'll need to be somewhat more specific.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    if let firstLocation = locations.first
```

The delegate signature that you were using wasn't quite what the delegate was looking for. With the signature corrected, you don't need the `as CLLocation` cast anymore.

I verified that it works with that change. For future reference, you could set a breakpoint at didUpdateLocations and you would see right away that it wasn't getting called and then work backwards from there.

Also make sure that Info.plist contains all the necessary location-related Privacy strings (I usually just put in all three to cover all the bases).